# ERC20 transfer showing as 0 but log shows different

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20

Checking the transaction https://www.etherchain.org/tx/e12af4940879c634a63d2c9629449695e07650a4e419e5822ddb18d8469e9948 anyone can check there were 3 DigixGold token transfers.

These transfers are valued as 0 in etherchain as well as in amberdata.io: https://amberdata.io/transactions/0xe12af4940879c634a63d2c9629449695e07650a4e419e5822ddb18d8469e9948. In etherscan these transfers aren't even shown: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe12af4940879c634a63d2c9629449695e07650a4e419e5822ddb18d8469e9948

If we check one of the log entries for this transaction we can spot this log entry related with the **transfer** function of the ERC20 token contract, and this transfer has a value different from 0 pictured in the last log's topic - source etherchain:

```
{
    "logindex": 0,
    "address": "0x55b9a11c2e8351b4ffc7b11561148bfac9977855",
    "data": "0x",
    "topics": [
      "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
      "0x000000000000000000000000c5ec6937d3278311e2ace517df214717310c0820",
      "0x0000000000000000000000005d2c24efac49825f682b5d334428f1a5c96acc09",
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c36"
    ]
  }
```

Considering this log entry is related with one of the transfers and its not 0 valued, why in these browsers they are shown as 0 valued transfers? Is there any piece of information that should be missing in order to read and figure out about these transfers?

Answer (score 2):

The target contract is a non standard ERC20 token.

It should have three topics, two indexed parameters and the event id and the transfer value in the data field.  But it has four topics instead.

```
"topics": [
  "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
  "0x000000000000000000000000c5ec6937d3278311e2ace517df214717310c0820",
  "0x0000000000000000000000005d2c24efac49825f682b5d334428f1a5c96acc09",
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c36"
]
```

Explorers fail in different ways while trying to cope with a non standard ERC20.